# buildozer error UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' in any project

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

i get same problem in any project:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('buildozer==1.4.1.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1024, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 93, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 180, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.compile_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 841, in compile_platform
    self._p4a(p4a_create, get_stdout=True)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 133, in _p4a
    return self.buildozer.cmd([*self._p4a_cmd, *cmd, *self.extra_p4a_args], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.10.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 316, in cmd
    stdout.write(chunk.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 7616-7677: ordinal not in range(256)
```

try remove .buildozer and other folders and buld again

Comment: Please share your `locale` command output.

Comment: `$ locale
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_TIME=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_NAME=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=kk_KZ.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

Comment: Try to execute `export LANG=C.UTF-8` then run buildozer again i same bash session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
dpkg-reconfigure locales
add RU-ru.UTF8 and EN-en.UTF8 locales solve this issue!